# JBoss EAP 6 GA のドメインモードでモニタリングをリモートから行いたいがクライアントで接続エラーとなる

Tags: jboss

### 現象

WindowsクライアントからJBoss EAPで稼働しているJVMをJConsoleから監視したいが、service:jmx:remoting-jmx://サーバーIP:4447へ接続できませんでした　となる。
サーバー上でポートを確認 `netstat -ano | grep 4447` し、ポートが開いていることを確認している。firewallは開発環境であるため無効にしている。

### 手順

[RedHat Customer Portal - ドメインモードで JConsole から JBoss に接続する](https://access.redhat.com/ja/solutions/2402771) の手順に従い、JBossの設定を変更した。
JBossはリモートのサーバー上(linux 64bit)で動作しており、クライアントはWindows 10 64bit。
クライアントのJDK(1.8)に含まれるjconsole.exeを実行し、
ログインは `service:jmx:remoting-jmx://サーバーIP:4447` を指定し、ユーザーID/パスワードを指定した。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JConsoleがJMXへ接続する方法がベンダ固有のものとなるため、JConsoleに対してライブラリを指定しなくてはなりません。

batファイル等でJBossのライブラリを指定することで接続可能になる。

```
set JBOSS_HOME=jbossのインストールディレクトリ
set JAVA_HOME=JREへのパス
set CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\client\jboss-cli-client.jar
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=%CLASSPATH%
```

参考資料: [Remote JMX access to WildFly using JConsole](https://dzone.com/articles/remote-jmx-access-wildfly-or)